# Which statistical test to use to compare 2 tests/measurements against a gold standard

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance

I'd like to know how best to go about comparing 2 tests/measurements against a gold standard.  Say I have 100 patients with 3D printed models and CT scans of their hands, and I'll measure a couple parameters (finger length, finger diameter, overall hand size, etc.).  If the measurement on the patient is considered the gold standard, how would I determine whether the model or the scan is better/closer to the true measurement?  Would I subtract the true value from the measured value and run a paired t-test on the residuals between the groups (model-patient vs. scan-patient)?

Also, how would the situation change if the patients only had either the CT scan or the model and therefore were no longer paired?  Does it boil down to using a unpaired T-test?